# Fast power algorithm realization

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to calculate a quadratic residue. Prime p is 3 mod 4 and is a very big number, about `1e38` (constexpr). I found only the formula of Lagrange `x = +- a^((p + 1)/4) mod p`.

I need to calculate powers of big numbers (`a ^ 1e38`). I was trying to use `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int`, but seems it has no sense. May be somebody knows a good realization, for such calculations or alternative algorithm.

Comment: Are you sure you want to raise to `1e38` power, and not multiply by `1e38`? For `x == 2`, the resulting number would take `1e38` bits to represent, which is billions of yottabytes, much more than all available storage combined.

Comment: I need to calculate powers about 1e38. If it is impossible with cpp_int representation, I need other. Standard calculator in Ubuntu Studio can calculate for example 5×10¹²⁸ mod 251 and give the answer 20 without delay I can feel

Comment: 5 times `10^128` is not at all the same thing as 5 raised to `10^128` power. Which one do you want?

Comment: I need to calculate a quadratic residue using formula of Lagrange `a ^ (n + 1)/4`

Comment: As @IgorTandetnik said, the int representation is insufficient because the whole universe is by far too small to represent all digits of such powers. You are probably thinking of a modular representation, for which ordinary arithmetic can be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, testing if something is a quadratic residue is done with a Euclidean algorithm-style calculation by invoking via quadratic reciprocity to flip the Jacobi symbols (or Kronecker symbols) whenever the top is smaller than the bottom.

---

Also, you should pretty much never compute an exponent *then* reduce modulo `p`: your exponentiation algorithm (e.g. square-and-multiply) should reduce modulo `p` after every step or so of its calculation. Key phrase: "modular exponentiation".

Answer (score 1):

Your example asked for modular arithmetic modulo a prime. As stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem, where p is a prime a^p mod p = a, and if a is not a multiple of p then a^(p-1) = 1 mod p. So if a != 0, then a^x = a^(x mod p-1). If you want something modulo a number not prime, then factor it and use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem.

If you want arithmetic of the reals, use a^x = exp(x * ln(a)) but for large x you will probably need to keep it as a logarithm to avoid overflow.

Comment: For `a ^ (n + 1)/4` if I use prime 251 `a^x = a^(x mod p-1)` gives the same a ^ 63.... Not better. I can't to find other algorithm for  quadratic residue. prime is 3 mod 4

Answer (score 0):

i think it may help
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modular-exponentiation-power-in-modular-arithmetic/

```
/* Iterative Function to calculate (x^y) in O(log y) */

int power(int x, unsigned int y) 
{ 

    int res = 1;     // Initialize result 

    while (y > 0) 
    { 
        // If y is odd, multiply x with result 
        if (y & 1) 
            res = res*x; 

        // y must be even now 
        y = y>>1; // y = y/2 
        x = x*x;  // Change x to x^2 
    } 
return res; 
}
```